# Find the positive integral solutions under certain conditions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

*find the positive integral solutions the equation*
$$ a+b+c+d+e=20,$$   where $a=b$ and $b,c,d,e$ are distinct.

*Need good approach, so I can apply on big number too thanks !*

Comment: What do you mean by $b\neq c\neq d\neq e$?  Nonequality is not transitive.  Do you only require that $b$ be different than $c$ and $c$ be different than $d$ but $b$ is allowed to be the same as $d$?  Such as $2\neq 3\neq 2$?  How about $a$ and it's involvement here, did you really mean for $a$ to be equal to $b$ rather than not equal?

Comment: For example (1,1,2,3,13) a=b, c,d,e don't match with any one

Comment: Then you say that by saying $a=b$ and $b,c,d,e$ are all distinct.  You don't chain together not-equal signs, that is bad form.

Comment: Only the first two digits equal always rest digits are distincts with each other

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm for finding all solutions to this diophantine equation?  As in, do you want the list of sets $(1,1,2,3,13), (1,1,2,4,12), (1,1,2,5,11), ... , (7,7,3,2,1)$ ?

Comment: yes, exactly @andrew I want that algorithm

Comment: I assume you're going to have a program in an environment that outputs these sets for you.  Perhaps you can start off with the three that I have given you, and try to recognize a pattern, then run a loop until you find all the sets?  What have you tried so far?  Otherwise, I can imagine that you'd be writing (by hand) over a hundred of these sets.

Answer (score 1):

For moderate numbers (32 bit integers), you could use [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/):

```
include "globals.mzn";
set of int: Domain = 1..100;
var Domain: a;
var Domain: b;
var Domain: c;
var Domain: d;
var Domain: e;

constraint a == b;
constraint all_different([b, c, d, e]);
constraint (a+b+c+d+e) == 20;
```

Output:

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = 13;
d = 3;
e = 2;
```